# Not able to Configure Analytics in the Admin dashboard of WSO2

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I am not able to Configure analytics in the Admin dashboard of WSO2. Even on starting the DAS server on port 9446 and APIM on 9443. I am going exactly as per the guide (link below) but still facing issues. kindly help.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Quick+Start+Guide#QuickStartGuide-SubscribingtotheAPI

In the link above, sroll down and refer to Monitoring APIs and viewing statistics section. After carefully following all the steps, upon saving configurations and then seeing the statistics in the store, it still says to configure DAS. There is an "index out of bounds" error.
[Click here to see the error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbRUa.png)

Comment: can you post the error log  with your question.

Comment: I did now Jenananthan, please check it out.

Comment: Is DAS running on a clustered setup or a standalone setup?

Comment: It is a standalone setup Jason.